# Open file directly from SharePoint path with CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have a SharePoint server and I want to open files **directly** from the Server with SharePoint CSOM.

User clicks button --> the file (Excel, Word, ...) opens at the client machine with the standard software.

Directly means, that if I change something to the file and click save, that the file is directly saved on the SharePoint server (or if I click e.g. 'Save as' in Excel the suggested path is 'https://sharpoint.url.com/folder').

Actually I have:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sharpoint.url.com");
string relativePath = "/folder/file.xls";
clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath);

clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

What do I have to do now, if I want to open the file directly (no download)?

Comment: What do you mean `open the file directly (no download)`? You have a file to a link on the web server. If you want to read it, you need to download it to disk, or read the data from the stream. Are you asking how to access the stream instead of saving to disk perhaps?

Comment: Is it possible to open the file from the stream? At the end, I want an open Excel file (opened with the Excel application from the Client) and if I Change something and hit 'Save', it should be saved directly at my SharePoint Server.

Comment: the file *is* the stream. If you want *Excel* to open the file though, you have to save it *locally*, or pass the URL directly to Excel. It already knows how to open Sharepoint files. In fact, the SharePoint UI allowed this since 2003 at least. Furthermore, simply clicking the URL should be enough to start Excel and load the file *IF* the library and browser settings permit it. It's the same thing when you click on a PDF file in a library and see it open instead of saving.

Comment: The library settings control the value of the `content-disposition` header sent when you send an HTTP GET request to get the file. If the value is `attachment`, the file must be saved. The *browser* may allow or prevent opening the file directly. Finally, Excel knows about SharePoint and document libraries already and can work with URL paths.

Comment: BTW none of this is related to programming, it's SharePoint configuration and UI. A lot of what people think as "SharePoint Developoment" is nothing more that configuration and administration. MSDN docs don't help either - they actually cause harm by *not* covering SP administration or explaining the features and how they are used. You'll find that in Technet. For years, people created webparts in code to change how grids looked because MSDN didn't explain how eg the DataViewWebPart worked or how you could style a grid from the UI.

Comment: Finally, a more appropriate site for such questions would be sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you ask how to access the file's stream instead of downloading it to a local folder.

You can use the [File.OpenBinaryDirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537083.aspx) method to get access to its ETag and stream, eg :

```
using(var fileInfo=File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext,"/folder/file.xls"))
using(var reader=new StreamReader(fileInfo.Stream))
{
    //Do whatever you want with the data
}
```

BTW you *shouldn't* use the old `xls` files. The format is deprecated for over 10 years. The current Excel format, xlsx, is a zipped package of XML files that's *better* supported by SharePoint itself, doesn't require Excel to generate or read.

For example, if you wanted to read cell values from an `xlsx` file, you could use the popular EPPlus library to read directly from the stream:

```
using(var fileInfo=File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext,"/folder/file.xlsx"))
using(var package=new ExcelPackage(fileInfo.Stream))
{
    var sheet=package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
    var value=ws.Cells["A1"].Value;
    //...
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems the question isn't related to programming after all. All that's needed to save or open a SharePoint document is clicking on the document's link. What happens then depends on the `Open Documents in Client Applications` setting at the site and document library level.

This affects the headers the server sends to the browser when the user clicks on a document link. The *browser* may still refuse to open the registered application and display the `Save` dialog.

If that doesn't work, you should check *why* instead of writing code. It's probably a configuration error or a browser setting. Solving it is easier than creating workarounds, pushing them to all client machines. And then keeping track of all the patches, where they are deployed and deploying new ones.

Apart from that, the Office applications know about SharePoint and document libraries since 2003. They can browse them, display *SharePoint* properties for the document, show collaborators etc.

As I mentioned in the question comments, a **lot** of what people think as "SharePoint Developoment" is nothing more that configuration, administration and *end user* features.

MSDN docs don't help either - they actually cause harm by not covering SP administration or explaining the features and how they are used. You'll find that in Technet. For years, people created webparts in code to change how grids looked because MSDN didn't explain how eg the DataViewWebPart worked or how you could style a grid from the UI.

In general, the best place for such questions is http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. For example, check [“Open in the client application” Vs “Use the server default (Open in the client application)” inside the document library advance settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204574/open-in-the-client-application-vs-use-the-server-default-open-in-the-client)

Comment: I've read several threads with `File.OpenBinaryDirect`. But how can I open the file from `StreamReader`? O how can I pass the stream to Excel? Btw: `xls` was just an example. We use `xlsx`.

Comment: @Beetee that's not what you asked and you don't need any code to open SharePoint files in Excel. Excel already understands about document libraries, it can read from URLs directly and even display the *SharePoint* document's properties.

Comment: @Beetee updated, including a link to a related question in sharepoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

We can create Map Network Drive for SharePoint library, and open the file from the network location. Check article below:

http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-webdav-sharepoint-2013

Or we can download the file from SharePoint and open it using the code below:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\YourWorkbook.xlsx");
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3k79a5x.aspx

Comment: That's not what the OP asked at all.

Comment: You can only use a network drive when the *client* machine runs the WebClient service, WebDAV is enabled on the SharePoint server *and* network. WebClient doesn't run on startup and many networks don't allow WebDAV for security reasons

Comment: @LZ-SPWX: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm searching for. The process should be invisible for the user. He shouldn't notice, where the file is opened and closed.